# Ubuntu 14.04 keyboard layout issue

Tags: keyboard, layout

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04 and I added a new keyboard layout(romanian) then I added Alt+Shift as hotkey for switching to another layout using Tweak Tool.

If I press alt+shift, the language indicator shows the other layout but still it uses the default one. If I click on the language indicator and choose ro layout, it works.

What may be the problem?

Edit: I noticed that if I press alt-shift for a longer time, then it switches and works in the other layout as expected.

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu!  ;-)  Could you convert your edit to an answer as that is the answer to your question...  (and that is why the default was changed ftom [Alt][Shift] to [Super][Space]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solution: Open dconf editor and go to: org>gnome>desktop>wm>keybindings and set
switch-input-source to

```
['<Alt>Shift_L']
```

and switch-input-source-backward to

```
['Alt+Shift']
```